# If I want to avoid quantifiers?

Tags: logic, soft-question

In mathematics quantifiers always is used with restrictions $\forall x\in A$ etc and mathematicians often write:
$$x\in A\implies p(x)\;\;\;\text{instead of}\;\;\;\forall x\in A:p(x).$$ 
Is there a counterpart expression for $\exists x\in A: p(x)$ without quantifier?

Is writing like this logical unobjectionable?

I'm interested in trying to replace 'predicate logic' in mathematics with a 'mathematical propositional algebra', that is, only use propositions of the type $x\in A\implies p(x)$. For such propositions $P_i$, there would be a "mathematical ring" with elements
$$\displaystyle
\bigoplus_i\bigwedge_j p_j^{n_i}.
$$
I guess it won't work but in the process I might learn something about logic and semantics.

Comment: @Dan Christensen: $x\in A\Rightarrow\neg(y\in B\Rightarrow (x,y)\notin f)$?

Comment: I would think that any quantifier-free logic would be unable to express something like $\forall x\in A: \exists y\in B: P(x,y)$.

Comment: @Dan Christensen: it's the same as above.

Comment: How would you distinguish statements like $\forall x: Q(x)$ from $Q(x)$? They can mean quite different things.

Comment: @Dan Christensen: yes,it only works in "math-style".

Comment: Then how do you distinguish $\forall x:[x\in A \implies P(x)]$ from $x\in A \implies P(x)$?

Comment: @Dan Christensen: those two are equivalent for me.

Comment: They are not equivalent. The 2nd statement applies only for a particular $x$.

Comment: @Dan Christensen: I read the second as "whenever $x\in A then P(x)$" and it seems as you can define them to be equivalent in a consistent way.

Comment: You have to think of these statements as lines in a formal proof. The statement $x\in A \implies P(x)$ or equivalently, $\neg [x\in A \land \neg P(x)]$ refers to a single object $x$. On the other hand, the statement $\forall x: [x\in A \implies P(x)]$ refers to potentially infinitely many objects. They are not equivalent statements. We must make a distinction between them.

Comment: If one wishes to hand-wave, of course for `∃x∈A P(x)` one could just write "$x_0{∈}A \land P(x_0)$" with the understanding that $x_0$ is some particular instance of $x.$ (In contrast, for that shorthand "$x{∈}A{⟹}P(x)$" for universal quantification, $x$ is understood as any arbitrary copy of $x.)$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fact that the universal quantifier on $x$ is omitted doesn't mean it's not supposed to be there. The correct parsing of $\forall x\in A: p(x)$ is $\forall x(x\in A\rightarrow p(x))$.

For existential quantifier this would be $\exists x(x\in A\land p(x))$. You may feel it is okay to omit the outer quantifier, but you have to remember it's still there.

Comment: But if you don't want to parse the mathematical expression to a correct logical expression, the mathematical expression is still rather consistent, isn't it? I can't see no disadvantages.

Comment: Did you undrestnad waht I am wrting here?

Comment: The point in that comment is that we can often do error correction in our brain, when the text is simple enough. This happens automatically and sometimes we don't even notice the misprints and typos. But as you increase the complexity, our ability to do this goes down. And eventually we stop understanding the written. Just because you can understand there is an omitted quantifier doesn't mean it's not really there. And if you want mathematical text to continue and be as little open to interpretations as possible, you need to remember these things, not chuck them aside casually.

Comment: I appreciated your answer and I'm gonna try the $A\wedge p(x)$ and see where it's heading to.

Comment: you may be right and then there is no point in my idea, because I had computer applications in mind.

Comment: All the more. Computers don't have our inherent ability to infer from context, so they don't have a very good auto-correct abilities.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to avoid using quantifiers, from a logical point of view (I mean logically, not in the sense of logic theory, I don't know much about that) the statements
$$
\forall x \in A : p(x) \qquad \text{ and } \qquad  x \in A \,\, \Rightarrow \,\, p(x)
$$
are equivalent just as 
$$
\exists x \in A : p(x) \qquad \text{ and } \qquad  x \in A \,\, \nRightarrow \,\, \neg p(x)
$$
are equivalent. I meant if you want to express yourself ; technically speaking the quantifiers are just not explicited but they are always there. Either way, if you want to avoid writing quantifiers, I highly suggest either the use of words or partial mathematical formulas (in the sense that you can put the quantifiers into words and put $p(x)$ in formulas for instance).

Hope that helps,

Comment: It's not possible for both of those pairs to be equivalences under the same set of conventions. If the free variable in "$x \in A \to p(x)$" is universally quantified, so is the free variable in "$x \in A \not\to \lnot p(x)$". But $(\exists x \in A) p(x)$ cannot, in general, be equivalent to any universally quantified formula.

Comment: Also, $x \in A \not\to\lnot p(x)$ is false if we consider any object $x$ that is *not* in $A$.

Comment: @Carl Mummert : I said "logically, not in the sense of logic theory". You could definitely write in a sentence "Not all elements of $A$ make $p(x)$ false, because we have a counter-example", which is what I wrote in symbols up there. So don't interpret my answer from a logic-theory point of view, I know it's not correct then. But then again, from a logic-theory point of view I would never write this and I would explicit my quantifiers.

Comment: @Carl Mummert : Note that I also assumed OP was not familiar with logic, but now with his edit this seems like a false assumption. Feel free to ignore my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Ther is **no** way to omit the $\exists$ quantifier in every context.

If we use the convention of omitting initial *universal* quantifiers, we assume that the sentence :

> $\forall x(x > 0)$

(which is *false* in the domain $\mathbb N$ of the *natural numbers*) can be abbreviated as :

> $x > 0$.

Consider now the *negation* of $\forall x(x > 0)$, i.e. $\lnot \forall x(x > 0)$, which is $\exists x \lnot (x > 0)$ i.e :

> $\exists x (x \le 0)$

which is *true* in $\mathbb N$, as expected.

If we start from $x > 0$ and negate it, we will have $\lnot (x > 0)$, i.e. :

> $x \le 0$.

According to our convention, this is an abbreviation for :

> $\forall x(x \le 0)$

which is *false* in $\mathbb N$.

Thus we have that the negation of a false *sentence* is also false, which is impossible.

Comment: My thought was that maybe the very simple logic in almost all mathematics could be expressed in a way that would simplify calculations in proofs. But I realize that logic is much closer to computer programming than mathematics is.

Comment: @Lehs - there is a sub-system of first-order logic without quantifiers; see Ian Chiswell & Wilfrid Hodges, [Mathematical Logic](http://www.amazon.com/Mathematical-Logic-Oxford-Texts/dp/0199215626/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1412076658&sr=8-1&keywords=ian+chiswell+%26+wilfrid+hodges+mathematical+logic) (2007) : **CH.5 Quantifier-free logic**. But of course the expressive capabilities are limited.

Answer (score 1):

If you begin a proof with $x \in A$ and demonstrate that $p(x)$ is valid, then its really the same thing as saying $\forall x ( x \in A \Rightarrow p(x))$

( Because if $x$ is not a free variable of $\phi \in \Gamma$ and $\Gamma \vdash \phi$ then $\Gamma \vdash \forall x \phi$, so its logical unobjectionable)

If your question is only about how mathematicians write, sometimes I see a clever avoidance of $\exists$: $p(x)$ for some $x \in A$

Comment: I'm interested how to write mathematics without quantifiers and am curios about that clever avoidance...

Comment: You cant REALLY avoid using quantifiers (maybe in PRA but...), that doesnt mean you need to spell them out, you can always use natural language or something like that

Comment: **Thanks everyone for helping me out from one of my delusions.**

Answer (score -1):

Considering the other answers, I conclude that it really is possible to exclude *quantifiers with limitations of the form* $x\in X$ ($\forall x\in X$ and $\exists x\in X$) without loss of information, when properly distinguishes between bounded and free variables. Obviously

$\forall x\in X:P(x)\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad a\in X\Rightarrow P(a)$

and here there are no problems with the interpretation of the alternatives. Less obvious  is

$\exists x\in X:P(x)\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad a\in X\wedge P(a)$

but successive reversible transformations shows:

$\exists x\in X:P(x)\;\Leftrightarrow\;\neg\forall x\in X:\neg P(x)\;\Leftrightarrow\;
\neg(a\in X\Rightarrow\neg P(a))\;\Leftrightarrow\;\neg(a\notin X\vee\neg P(a))\;\Leftrightarrow\;$$(a\in X\wedge P(a))$.

Not all the steps are equally easy to interpret, but never the less they are logical equivalents and it is more a psychological issue that it may be difficult to interpret a specific step in the chain. But the logical machinery works consistent. If one is interested of the interpretation of the statement one have to transform the statement to a more readable form ($\mathbb N_m=\{x\in\mathbb N|x>m\}$ and $\oplus$ is exclusive or below):

$1\oplus(\varepsilon\in\mathbb R_+)\oplus(\varepsilon\in\mathbb R_+)(m\in\mathbb N)
\oplus(\varepsilon\in\mathbb R_+)(m\in\mathbb N)(n\in\mathbb N_m)\oplus$
$(n\in\mathbb N_m)(|x-x_n|<\varepsilon)\Leftrightarrow$
$(\varepsilon\notin\mathbb R_+)\oplus(\varepsilon\in\mathbb R_+)(m\in\mathbb N)
(1+(n\in\mathbb N_m))\oplus(n\in\mathbb N_m)(|x-x_n|<\varepsilon)\Leftrightarrow$
$(\varepsilon\notin\mathbb R_+)\oplus(\varepsilon\in\mathbb R_+)(m\in\mathbb N)
(n\notin\mathbb N_m)\oplus(n\in\mathbb N_m)(|x-x_n|<\varepsilon)\Leftrightarrow$
$(\varepsilon\notin\mathbb R_+)\vee (m\in\mathbb N\wedge n\notin\mathbb N_m)\vee
(m\in\mathbb N\wedge|x-x_n|<\varepsilon)\Leftrightarrow$
$\varepsilon\in\mathbb R_+\Rightarrow m\in\mathbb N\wedge(n\in\mathbb N_m\Rightarrow |x-x_n|<\varepsilon)\Leftrightarrow$
$\forall\epsilon\in\mathbb R_+\exists k\in\mathbb N:n\in\mathbb N_{k}\Rightarrow |x-x_n|<\epsilon\Leftrightarrow \displaystyle \lim_{i\rightarrow\infty}x_i=x$.

Thus, the logic in (non meta) mathematics is substantially propositional logic.

In general predicate logic it is not always possible to eliminate quantifiers.

Comment: No. There is a world of difference between $\forall x . (P (x) \to Q)$ and $(\forall x . P (x)) \to Q$, and if you omit $\forall$ it is not possible to distinguish between the two.

Comment: @Zhen Lin: as I wrote, in general predicate logic it is not always possible to eliminate quantifiers.

Comment: Then what do you mean by your first paragraph?

Comment: @Zhen Lin: I mean that $\forall x\in X$-quantifiers and $\exists x\in X$-quantifiers may be replaced with propositional logical expressions.

Comment: See: Ian Chiswell & Wilfrid Hodges, *Mathematical Logic* (2007), chapter 5: Quantifier-free logic. (I just loaded it as pdf from a tip from Mauro ALLEGRANZA).

Comment: It is true that you can replace $\forall x \in X . P (x)$ with $\forall x . (x \in X \to P (x))$. But you can't get rid of $\forall$ entirely.

Comment: @Zhen Lin: I admit that perhaps there are no formal logical way to do it, but it is consistent in mathematics and reduce this kind of mathematical statements to propositional logic. Of course there is an extra semantic agreement, that: $(\forall x\in X:P(x))\leftrightarrow (a\in X\rightarrow P(a))$.